# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found

Tags: asp.net, iis, database-connection, connection-string

I deployed my application onto iis.Its working fine when i gave the connection string of local database

```
<add name="WPSConnectionString" connectionString="server=UXTSRV001\SQL2008;
   database=SupportPortal;Max Pool Size=10;uid=sa;pwd=password@123;" 
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /
```

But  when i gave the connection string of remote server i am getting the error

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found
```

The connection string is as follows

```
<add name="WPSConnectionString" connectionString="server=MYSERVER;   
database=UISupportPortal;Max Pool Size=10;uid=MYUSER;pwd=PASSWORD;"  
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: I've removed your actual connection string! Be careful...I recommend you changing the password for the given connection.